# How to sort the output of C++ program (stdout) via "| sort"

Tags: c++, bash, shell, stdout

I have a working program in c++ that creates a List and makes possible to fill that list with items (add), remove items, print items.

I want to test that add function works, so I create and run test.cc:

```
#include "List.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    List s;
    s.add("OMG Milk Factory", "Milk", 140, 2);
    s.add("Just Milk", "Milk", 80, 4);
    s.print(cout);
    return 0;
}
```

Because the print function shuffle items before printing, the output might be:

```
140 2 Milk OMG Milk Factory
80 4 Milk Just Milk
```

or

```
80 4 Milk Just Milk
140 2 Milk OMG Milk Factory
```

I create bash script and I want to sort the output of test.cc by using piping output to sort, but I do not know how. I have this one and it doesn't work:

```
compile_and_run() {
    rm -f ./a.out
    LANG=C run -C Build "g++ -std=c++17 -Wall  -I. ~/Documents/testcase/$1 libhw2.a && ./a.out"
}

compile_and_run test.cc | sort
test "Add 2 Element Function Test" exact '140 2 Milk "OMG Milk Factory"\n80 4 Milk Just Milk\n' stdout
```

How to correctly use `| sort` ?

Comment: I assume you want the items sorted numerically according to the numbers at the beginning of each line?  (e.g. "80" should be printed before "140"?).  If so, you'll need to pass the `-n` flag to `sort` to let it know you want a numeric-sort rather than an alphabetical-sort, e.g. `./my_program | sort -n`

Comment: Yes, I want them to be sorted according to numbers in the beginning of the line. I tried it ```compile_and_run test.cc | sort -n```.
But my script output is the following:
```Executing: g++ -std=c++17 -Wall  -I. ~/Documents/testcase/test2.cc libhw2.a && ./a.out```

So it seems like it does not execute ```| sort```

Comment: Try `./a.out | sort -n`

Comment: @r4sk01 you're passing everything including the output of the compiler to `sort`

Comment: Compile your code first, and only that.  This creates your executable. Then call it `./a.out | sort -n`.  Separate your build - run phases.  That way the only output that `sort` will process will be from  your executable, and compilation messages will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks everyone, kinda solved it for now via 
```LANG=C run -C Build "g++ -std=c++17 -Wall  -I. ~/Documents/testcase/$1 libhw2.a && ./a.out | sort"```
But understand concern of @Nic3500 and will separate build - run phases

Answer (score 0):

In your case you might just have to do

```
compile_and_run test.cc | sort -k1,1n
```

so that it sorts numerically in ascending order on the first column.